# 9v oscillator circuit that produces a frequency of 500 Hz

Tags: circuit-design, oscillator, 555

I am a gr 10 student that really has no idea what I am doing, however, I have made a circuit schematic and just need to know if it is right I guess.

[image: schematic]

Comment: What is your intended output? 0 to 9 volt sine wave centered on 4.5V?  Or do you want a square wave?

Comment: square wave----

Comment: The output inductor L and output capacitor C2 will make your wave less square.  For a square wave you should directly use the output pin 3.  I see you've done the frequency calculations, but have you done the on time vs off time calculations for your circuit to make sure it has a 50% duty cycle?  Can you point to your reference 555 circuit?  If you look at wikipedia you'll find the formulas for the astable circuit and you'll see that you only get close to 50% duty cycle if RB is orders of magnitude larger than RA.  You appear to have labelled RB 50k and also 12.2k?

Comment: 555 is a complicated thing. Me hobbyist newbies usually start with this cheat tutorial: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_timer.html.

Comment: @AaronRandhawa - Hi, Changing the title of your question to something so unrelated is not allowed here, as it could be considered vandalism - even if it is "your" own question, you have already made it public. It's too late to decide now that you want to hide the title, sorry. Therefore I am reversing that last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaron, Have you ever heard about a circuit simulator? It is a good way to learn a lot about circuits before you ever have to build one out of physical components.

I recommend you search for a free software package called LT-SPICE. This cool program lets you draw a circuit and then run a simulation on the circuit and look at the subsequent voltage and/or current waveforms produced by the circuit.

LT-Spice can be used with a model of the 555 timer chip so it should be a great learning experience for you to get familiar with a circuit simulator and the experiment with your specific circuit.

I decided to use LT-Spice to simulate a circuit similar to yours but made a number of changes to get it to oscillate at very close to 500Hz.

Changes Made:

1. Eliminated the L-C circuit on the output because it is not clear what that is intended to produce.
2. Purged the trim-pot on the pin 5 Control Voltage pin. You can apply frequency trimming later.
3. Adjusted RA, RB and C1 to standard component values to get the oscillation frequency to be very close to 500Hz.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Never thought about using a circuit simulator, but now that I think about this it could make my life 10x easier. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Holy guacamoly I am definitely going to use the circuit you made as a reference. This makes a lot more sense when I can see it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First -- not bad for someone who "doesn't know what they're doing".  Hang on to that, because I do have some critiques.

It looks like you're trying to trim the frequency with the pot at R1.  This is probably a bad idea -- if you need more precision than you can get out of a 555, then rather than trying to trim the frequency, you should find something with better precision.

If you *are* going to trim the frequency, then you don't need to call out an oddball capacitor value, so C1 can be 0.1uF.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the LC filter at the output of the thing, but you usually don't want to try to drive a coil with a logic output.  Moreover, it's going to be hard to find a coil with that high an inductance.  Unless you have some in hand, or have concrete plans on how to build it, find another way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really trying to do, but you may do better with a Wien bridge oscillator.

Comment: Just one more question if I were to leave the circuit as it is would it theoretically work?

Comment: I think it would, at least for a while.  You'd probably get output at pin 3, but it may not make it out the filter.  Without any load on the filter, if it's even a fairly high Q inductor the LC circuit will look like a short to ground at 590Hz; if you adjusted the circuit to that frequency you could damage the chip because it's not designed to drive such a load.  You could also see a considerable increase in the voltage on the cap over the voltage at pin 3 -- this could cause problems if you exceed the voltage capabilities of the cap.

Answer (score 2):

Why is the Reset input connected to part of the timing circuit?  If you want to make the standard 555 astable oscillator circuit adjustable so you can trim it to exactly 500 Hz, consider replacing Rb with a fixed and adjustable resistor in series.

Also, please add connection dots to your schematic so we can see what the circuit does.

If your goal is to filter a 500 Hz square wave to extract a sine wave, consider a different approach that starts with a symmetrical square wave.  This will reduce the distortion products in the resulting sine wave.  The circuit is in the LMC555 datasheet.  This is a CMOS version of the 555, but the circuit works well with the older bipolar versions.  The circuit has one timing resistor connected from the output back to the Trigger and Threshold inputs.